# Шейдер работает в эдиторе, но не работает в билде 2

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

В настройках Edit / Project Settings / Graphics расширил список включаемых шейдеров Always Included Shaders и добавил туда принудительно в конец свой шэйдер. Но в результате Шейдер отображается только в эдиторе. При компиляции в exe на PC так же не отображается.

[ССЫЛКА на этот шэйдер Bumped version](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Silhouette-Outlined_Diffuse)